# How are MISMO based XMLs are different from others?

Tags: xml, xmlhttprequest, xslt-1.0

I was going through how to get credit history from Equifax and i read a new type of xml which is "MISMO Xml".

How is MISMO xml different from normal xml and what are its uses?
thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to use capital letters to indicate the title of the question. We know it is the title because it is at the top.

Comment: Thanks, changed to small letters, do you know the answer?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but now your question looks pleasant and I am sure that someone who knows about it will answer it soon. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is super old, but MISMO is a specification used in the mortgage industry. It's still just XML.

http://www.mismo.org/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISMO